# Python function for Square in a provided list

Tags: python, function

I have a list like `[2,3,4,5]` and i want square of these number using python function

Have tried below Python code

```
def square(list=[]):
    for i in list:
        new_value=[]
        new_value.append(i**2)
        return new_value
```

I get the square of only first entry in a list.

```
square(2,3,4)
```

Comment: Function call should be square([2,3,4]).
It takes a single argument which is the list.

Comment: Having a variable named `list` is a bad idea!

Comment: I agree with @YuriGinsburg, I think you might be confusing taking a list of arguments and taking multiple arguments, amongst other things.

Comment: You recreate `new_value=[]` in every loop, so it will only ever contain the contents of the last loop executed. You will only get the first value because the `return` is inside the loop, so will be executed on the first iteration, exiting the function.

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension makes this function a single liner and much clearer.

```
def square(x): 
    return [y**2 for y in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method `square` is initialising `new_value` for every element in the list, and also your return is incorrectly placed inside the loop.

```
def square(list=[]):
    new_value=[]
    for i in list:
        new_value.append(i**2)
    return new_value
```

Comment: Having a variable named `list` is a bad idea.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Totally agreed. Our OP will figure out in due time with experience why it is a bad idea.

Comment: The best part is that not even 15 minutes ago I saw another question where someone’s code was broken because of exactly that; a variable named `list`.